Click on Edit Link image on webpage VBA
I am automating a web page. Trying to open a link and update fields on the webpage. It's an HTML table having multiple rows and columns. I wanted to click on the specific link (Edit Comment image link) in one of the columns. Once I click it will open new page. The HTML code looks like below.

Inside tr tag I have below a tag
<A href="http://abcd.efgh.local/Apps/Internal/Reports/Matched/MatchedItems.asp#"><IMG onclick=EditxxxComments(91,66149); border=0 alt="Edit Comment" src="http://abcd.efgh.local/images/btn_edit.gif"></A>

Wanted to click on edit image:

I have written a code that can go inside "a" tag but not sure how to trigger a click event and open the link.
Sub GetAttritbutesImgTag()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim Link As Object
Dim ecol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://abcd.efgh.local/Apps/Internal/Reports/Matched/MatchedItems.asp?parm=91"

Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set html = ie.document

Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("img")

For Each Link In ElementCol
    
    If Link.innerHTML = "EditComments(91,66149);" Then     ' tried ; adding n removing it
        Link.Click
    End If
Next

Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol

    If Link.innerHTML = "EditComments(91,66149);" Then    ' tried ; adding n removing it
        Link.Click
    End If
    
    If InStr(Link.innerHTML, "EditComments(91,66149);") Then     ' tried ; adding n removing it
        Link.Click
    End If
    
    If Link.getAttribute("onclick") = "EditComments(91,66149);" Then ' tried ; adding n removing it
        Link.Click
    End If
    
Next

Set ie = Nothing
End Sub

I have masked sensitive data.
Appreciate if anybody can look into it and provide help.
Thanks in advance.

First, I would suggest that you post more of the relevant html code to determine whether there's a more efficient solution.  Otherwise, try the following...
Dim i as Long

With html.querySelectorAll("a > img")
    For i = 0 To .Length - 1
        If .Item(i).getAttribute("alt") = "Edit Comment" Then
            .Item(i).parentElement.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

You'll notice that it's checking the "alt" attribute of the image for "Edit Comment".

Thank you so much for your valuable time, #Copilot helped me and this is the code it gave,
Set imgs = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")
For i = 0 To imgs.Length - 1
    If InStr(imgs.Item(i).getAttribute("onclick"), "EditComments(91,66149)") > 0 Then
        imgs.Item(i).Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


@user26706841 That's great, glad you were able to find a solution.  And thanks for your feedback, cheers!
